# Can we export the Entity Data in CRM Solution along with Entities (CRM 5.0)

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I am moving my CRM Solution from Local and importing that in Development Environment.
Wondering if there is any way to export the Data along with the Entities?

Appreciate your Responses.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as part of the solution package, no. Try exporting it to excel and then importing through the import wizard.

Comment: It would have been nice if that option is there. Hopefully they will come up with that option in future releases. That's a pain to export the data for all entities.

Answer (score 0):

I'm about to try the Reference Data Transporter from MSCRM 2011 ToolKit: http://mscrmtoolkit.codeplex.com/documentation#referencedatatransporter

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with that so now I'm trying the Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Instance Adapter as recommended by a guy at Microsoft partner support.

However, I can't get this to install properly. In fact the installation is generally tortuous.